# netbeans duplicate file shortcut

Tags: file-management, shortcuts, netbeans

To duplicate a file I'm currently right clicking copy and then pasting on the 'parent' folder. Thats not exactly perfect especially if the 'parent' directory is several screen scrolls up.

Is there a keyboard or whatever short cut to make a duplicate of the selected file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're making copies of the same file multiple times you should set that file as a template.

Right click on it and click set as template.

Now, besides that, there isn't any integrated funcionality to speed up copying of files unless you open a separate file browser and use that for quick copy-and-paste and then just refresh your project in NetBeans using F5.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Files are different so it looks like I'll have to look outside netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

As I know this feature does not exist in netbeans unless you create a template. You can use Dreamweaver and simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate any file you want.

Answer (score 0):

For Java files you can use `Copy...` (Refactor) and assign it e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

This doesn't work on other files as far as I can see but allows simplification of my Java editing workflow.